# backup sql script is cannot run after changing server 2012 from domain to workgroup

Tags: sql-server

Had to go from server 2012 as domain server to workstation.
All is working well and the users can access sql databases with sa login.
The server was running a sql script to backup the databases in task manager.
This is not working anymore. When i see the reports file is says:
The server principal "WYNSSERVER\Administrator" is not able to access the database "PW0001SOC" under the current security contex.
What to do, already tried to open the database in Management studio nad when execute the scipt is working when i connected the database under SQL sa login. But here it is running as Administrator.
How to solve this ?

Comment: "Task manager" do you mean "Task Scheduler"? Have you considered running it as an SQL Server Agent job?

Comment: it is a bat  file that runs in task scheduler
E:
cd E:\sqlbackups\dinsdag\
del *.* /Q
sqlcmd -S WYNSSERVER\POPSY -i C:\comsql\sqlbackupdi.sql -o E:\sqlbackups\dinsdag\reports.txt
blat E:\sqlbackups\dinsdag\reports.txt -s "SQLbackup" -i "sql report" -to hofmans@whboekhouding.be
exit

Comment: You need to add the `sa` username and password to `sqlcmd` command. Because now that the server is not on the domain, the username that executes the task is no longer trusted to access the DB

Comment: Now would be a good time to go review (or perhaps write) your DR documentation and update details like this with any changes you make. Your documentation should mention all these accounts, directories, machines, scripts/files and their purpose.